# Where to see SEC filings for companies that only trade on TSX

Tags: canada, sec

For a Canadian company that only trades in TSX and none of the US exchanges, is there a Canadian equivalent of SEC filings? Which website will have that info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SEDAR](http://www.sedar.com/search/search_form_pc_en.htm)

They also have prospectuses for ETFs and mutual funds,
http://www.sedar.com/search/search_form_mf_en.htm